# VSFTPD command ls hang

Tags: ftp

I have a ftp server with vsftpd. and if I do command ls always hang. Previously run well, some of the time when I log back in when this happens like this.

```
user@serverubuntu:~$ ftp localhost
Connected to localhost.
220 SERVER FTP
Name (localhost:user): usernametes
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> ls
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
150 Here comes the directory listing.
```

And hang.

Below my config vsftpd.conf in /etc/

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
anon_world_readable_only=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
nopriv_user=www-data
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/vsftpd.pem
guest_enable=YES
guest_username=www-data
local_root=/var/www/vhosts/$USER/httpdocs/
user_sub_token=$USER
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd_user_conf
local_max_rate=2000000 # bytes per sec, 2Mbytes per sec
max_clients=50 # to avoid DOS attack, if you have a huge server, increase this..
ftpd_banner=SERVER FTP
```

Server using ubuntu server 10.4 lucid. And vsftpd using virtual user which users I get from mysql.

Thanks.

Comment: i recomend u check log of vsftpd.

Answer (score 0):

In corporate scenarios, this problem is most commonly due to excessively high file counts in the FTP home directory of the user you're logging in as. (example: thousands of images)

Execute `ls -1 | wc -l` in that user's FTP home and verify whether or not this is the case. If it is, there's not a whole lot that can be done other than choosing a better way of organizing the files (not always an option), or avoiding listing the directory over FTP.